# Yii 2.0 - How to get the id value of current record then save it to particular field?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to create record where the particular field to be save contains the value of current model's id plus the format I made.

To get the id value I've tried to make Controller like this:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new NomorSurat();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
        {
            // Save nosurat field with particular format name
            $model->save(); // I save to get the current ID here, but return value still nothing
            $number = $model->id;
            $bulan = date('m');
            $tahun = date('Y');
            // Save with current id + custom format
            $model->nosurat = $number.'/'.'BTPN-TMH'.'/'.Yii::$app->joenmarz->romanic_number($bulan).'/'.$tahun;

            ... // some stuff

            // Then save it all, once again
            $model->save();

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

But the variable $number saved in nosurat field returns only the custom format I've made, when I tried it in my View:

```
...
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'nosurat',
        ... // some attributes
    ],
]) ?>
```

Here's screenshot of the result:
[image: Result Screenshot]

Comment: y r u saving the same model twice?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a method to your model which returns the current id and what you have saved in your database on the attribute `nosurat` like below and use this function for display.

```
public function getNosuratDisplay()
{
    return $this->id.$this->nosurat;
}
```

This of course would make it more difficult if you want to query for that attribute because the id isn't saved in the database.

So i guess the best solution would be to generate and save this attribute in afterSave (e.g. only generate the id in insert mode i guess this is what you want).

```
public function generateNosurat()
{
   $number = $this->id;
   $bulan = date('m');
   $tahun = date('Y');
   $this->nosurat = $number.'/'.'BTPN-TMH'.'/'.Yii::$app->joenmarz->romanic_number($bulan).'/'.$tahun;
}

public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
{
    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
    if ($insert) {
        $this->generateNosurat();
        $this->save();
    }
}
```